# Language Selector

Tags: usability, language

I need to integrate a language selector in my app with 2 ones:

- Spanish
- Basque

I have two options, adding "Spanish / Basque" but, in responsive I need the prefixes, but I'm unable to find the contraction. I know that Spanish is "ESP", but Basque? I think It's EUS (Basque is Euskera in spanish).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the type of code you are using there are a few possibilities. In general I find that the ISO 639 codes are used most of the time.

If you want to use those codes then the options would be the following

- **Spanish**: *es* or *spa*
- **Basque**: *eu, eus* or *baq*

Usually, in code (!) and not UI's, these are also used in combination with the ISO country code. For Spain this would mean you end up with these:

- **Spanish**: *ES-es* or *ES-spa*
- **Basque**: *ES-eu, ES-eus* or *ES-baq*

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes

*Has link to the original reference which is less pretty to read :-)*

Comment: Normally in the tag the language comes first, so es-ES and eu-ES, and the case is for clarity. I once worked with an open source project that misidentifed French Canadian as CA-fr so I had to demonstrate that the app would load up Catalan language resources when they were available instead of French. fr-CA was the correct tag.

Answer (score 5):

- Spanish could be **ESP** or **SPA** (find out which one is a better fit for your users).
- Basque could be **BAQ** or **EUS** (make sure you select what the Basque population would recognise).

  **Important:** I would use EUS short for Euskera only if the Basques recognise Euskera as Basque. Remember that you are providing
  the language option for the Basque population not the Spanish speaking
  one.

[image]

[image]

**References:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basque_language

https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes_name.php?code_ID=47